# tf.Print not printing in console

Tags: tensorflow

I am running a TensorFlow code in console (not Jupyter notebook) and despite me using `tf.Print`, it does not print anything. The usage is as follows :

```
#This is during Graph construction
                    elem = train_get_list[i]
                    img = elem[0]
                    label = elem[1]
                    img = tf.Print(img, [tf.shape(img)], "The shape of input is :")
                    elemshape.append(img)
                    net, networksummaries =  overfeataccurate(img,numclasses=1000, phase=phasecond)
```

Later during session :

```
[val_accu, summaries,_] = sess.run([running_accuracy, validation_summary_op, img])
```

The above does not print anything and nor does the following print anything :

```
[val_accu, summaries,_] = sess.run([running_accuracy, validation_summary_op,elemshape])
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your code seems alright, can you post some runable code?

Comment: I seem to have solved it. In the beginning of my code I had put the following line :
`os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` . When I commented it, it started displaying the statements of tf.Print(). Right now, I am looking for a way to make it print to a log file rather than at the console.

Comment: sounds like a useful idea. can you post your solution when you find it? right now, only thing come to my mind is console redirection, since tf.Print is printing message to std error, so message in log file should not be too messy.

Comment: I'll be sure to do that.